# Android application localization without /res/values/

Tags: android, localization

I have developed an Android application and all strings are displayed in English, as English is the default language on my device.

I wish to display strings in different Indian languages without making any changes to the apk (or at minimal, most changes to the apk file).

Can it be done without having to include specific strings.xml file in the /res/values-locale folder?

Comment: No, you can't do this. Where else would the localized strings come from?

Comment: Only possible if the localized string came from webservice data... otherwise you can't.